# Is there a way to run Adobe CC programs that require Windows 10 on Windows Server 2016 Essentials?

Tags: compatibility, windows-server-2016, adobe-creative-cloud

I am a video creator, and I am looking to offload the heavy rendering from my main computer (running Windows 10) to my home server (currently running CentOS 7, although I'm not attached to that operating system).  I know that Adobe Premiere video won't render directly on Linux, so I thought I might use my otherwise-unused Windows Server 2016 Essentials license.  Is there a way to get Adobe Media Encoder to run on Server 2016?  Or do I need to go out and get another Win10 license?

If this belongs on Server Fault as opposed to here, I apologize.  I was under the impression that since it isn't being used by a business (yet!) this question belongs here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Server 2016 is based on Redstone 1, the same as Windows 10 1607.  Server 2019 is based on Redstone 5, the same as Windows 10 1809.  Adobe Media Encoder CC version 13 requires Windows 10 1703 or newer.

Even though Adobe doesn't list Windows Server as a supported operating system, I would expect it to work on Server 2019, but not Server 2016.

Comment: Thank you!  It's looking like the best course would probably be to set up a VM using a new Win10 license.

Comment: @Jason can you share a link that shows how the versions of Windows are related to the versions of Redstone?

Comment: @enharmonic From WP, [Windows 10 Version History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history), [Windows Server 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2016), [Windows Server 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2019)

Answer (score 0):

By default windows server will block installation due to IE Enhanced Security Configuration. You will have to disable it by opening the Server Manager. I have shown how to do this on this YouTube Video: https://youtu.be/E46PMd4i_Gk

Comment: You should explain all the steps needed in your answer. Links to external sites may eventually suffer from link-rot and make the answer useless.